# How to get data attribute in javascript -- not working on ios safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, safari

I'm unsuccessful at extracting a data attribute using javascript jQuery code running under ios safari (on my iPad).  The code I have works fine on desktop browsers.

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv" data-mine="test"></div>
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
console.log($('#mydiv').data("mine"));
```

the log for my ios Safari shows `undefined` whereas the log for desktop Chrome says `test` as it should.  I've tried some variations like

```
console.log($('#mydiv').data().mine);
```

and

```
console.log($('#mydiv').dataset.mine);
```

but those have not worked any better.

Comment: what's the version of the jQuery you're using?

Comment: You should investigate using the Safari web debugger: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/6rn54ycy/3/embedded/result/ -- cannot reproduce.

Comment: @AminJafari sorry, I don't know the version, I'll have to ask around!

Comment: @Blazemonger did you test this on an iPad?  I'm afraid I can't at the moment.

Comment: iPhone, but AFAIK it's the same Safari.

Comment: Yes, should be the same on iPhone although I haven't tried that myself.  Could be some additional factor at work here, but I don't know what it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why jquery is giving you the problem, but you could do it nativley

```
console.log( document.getElementById( 'mydiv' ).getAttribute( 'data-mine' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks, should have thought of that myself!  I plugged that in and it worked like a charm, don't really care why the jQuery didn't work.

Comment: or simply console.log(  mydiv.dataset.mine  )

Comment: dataset would work, but its a bit slower (not an issue for this instance), and doesn't have IE support, if that matters.

Comment: @dandavis I just tried your suggestion, that is much nicer thanks!

Comment: @AlanMoore: yeah, it doesn't work in old IE and stuff, so don't use it in prod, but it's very handy syntax for debugging real browsers.

Comment: @BlakeA.Nichols thanks for that note, lack of IE support would be a problem!